# R - How do I reference a variable by the column position?

Tags: r, syntax

I have a matrix / data frame of a bunch of variables.  How do I reference it when I am setting it to a formula?

Example: Let's say I have some data set as:

`data = read.csv(data_location, sep = ',')`

and since it's high dimensionality I don't spell out each column (which I could otherwise use c(col)).  Normally on lower dimensionality content I'd spell out each content.  Say it's called TARGET, but now I left it as data[50].

```
fit <- rpart(TARGET ~ ., data = train1, method = "anova")
```

I can't just say

```
fit <- rpart(data[50] ~ ., data = train1, method = "anova")
```

as it says "invalid type (list) for variable 'data[50]'.  How do I reference this with the proper syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data[, 50]` should work since `data[50]` will return a data.frame (list) instead of the contents of that data.frame, which is what you need. Try `class(data[50])` and `class(data[, 50])` to see the difference.